# Set Caching timeout Sitecore 8.1

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

How to set the caching timeout of renderings in sitecore 8.1?

I applied the code suggested in the below link but did not work.

http://www.reinoudvandalen.nl/blog/add-sliding-expiration-on-sitecore-rendering-cache/

I also try adding the below code in action method of a controller but still not working.

```
RenderingContext.CurrentOrNull.Rendering.Caching.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
```

Is there any other way I could try so I could set timeout for each rendering?

Comment: How did you apply the code? Did you register the pipeline in config? I must admit that I havent tested this yet in Sc8 though.

Comment: I replace the entry in sitecore.mvc.config

Comment: I have recently used Reinoud's approach successfully on 8.1 and validated it with a timestamp on the rendering view.

Comment: How did you test it is not working? for automatically release the memory you need a Scavengable = true cache. the htmlcache is default not Scavengable. but beside that it should work. And don't use nested caching with expiration. http://sitecore.stockpick.nl/english/custom-cache/

Answer (score 1):

You could use this attribute (above the action) to set a cache timeout:

```
 [OutputCache(Duration = 200)]
 public ActionResult ProductDetail()
 {
   ....
```

Comment: does this work for a Sitecore MVC Controller Renderings? It doesnt seem to be working for me. In sitecore i have the rendering as Cacheable and in the ControllerAction i added outputcache with duration set to 60s. But it isnt expiring after a minute. Did you have to do anything else?